# iTerm2 keyboard shortcut for moving tabs around

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iterm

Say I want to place one tab next to another. Currently I do this by clicking and dragging. This increases productivity because if I'm switching between 2 regular tasks in iTerm I want to place the tabs next to each other so I can switch between them quickly.

I can **switch** between tabs using keyboard shortcuts cmd+} and cmd+{.

But is there a way to **move** tabs around using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: I actually came here looking for a way to switch tabs as opposed to moving them around. Thanks :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's a default features. Just open preferences/Keys and in Global Shortcut keys you can assign keys to "Move tabs to left/right".

Personnaly i use Cmd + n/p

Comment: I don't see the "Move tabs to left/right" option in the list of actions to assign global shortcut keys. Are you using iTerm2?

Comment: Yeah i do use Iterm2 : Build 1.0.0.20120203

Comment: Yeah it used to crash when I updated it, but now it's fine. Thanks!

Comment: thks, use Cmd + jk  like vim

Answer (score 101):

Using predefined shortcuts in iTerm2 you can

**Move tabs**

Left: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

Right <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

And according to http://teohm.com/blog/2012/03/22/working-effectively-with-iterm2 you can

**Switch between tabs**

Next tab: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Previous tab: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: Switching between tabs actually can be easier to remember:

Left: `Cmd + Left`
Right: `Cmd + Right`

To move tabs, just also press Shift:

Left: `Cmd + Shift + Left`
Right: `Cmd + Shift + Right`

Comment: I tried Cmd+Shift+[. It didn't work, although Cmd+[ works. Does Cmd+Shift+[ make any sense? Isn't it just Cmd+{ ?

Comment: Gamechanger, thanks y'all.

Answer (score 20):

for me

```
 CMD + [   // for previous tab 
 CMD + ]  // for next tab
```

version `3.1.3`

Answer (score 10):

The defaults are `CMD + SHIFT + ]` and `CMD + SHIFT + [`. 
There are also available menus under the Window in the top bar.

You can also hit `CONTROL + TAB`

Comment: Moving tabs, not moving between tabs.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> will let you navigate split panes in the direction of the arrow, i.e. when using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to split panes vertically, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will let you switch between the panes.

Note: <kbd>⌥</kbd> is the [alt] key

Answer (score 6):

I reckon , screen shot will help . Please check key mappings section.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

alt + cmd + left/right

It works like charm for me.

Comment: You can also arrow up/down to switch between panes.

Answer (score 3):

Iterm2 Build 3.2.7 on High Sierra (10.13.6):  simply two keys:

CMD + Right_Arrow: move to next tab      ===  CMD + Shift + ]

CMD + Left_Arrow: move to previous tab   ===  CMD + Shift + [

Answer (score 3):

Here are the default hotkeys in iTerm2 3.3.12. You can change the key by going to Preferences > Keys.

[image: iTerm2 3.3.12]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the current (Build 1.0.0.20131228) default bindings for moving tabs is `Cmd + Shift + Left/Right`.